# How exactly does Tom Apostol's proof of the limit quotient property work?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

In *Calculus*, Apostol writes the following proof:

Proof of (iv). Since the quotient $f(x) / g(x)$ is the product of $f(x) / B$ with $B / g(x)$, it suffices to prove that $B / g(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow p$ and then appeal to (iii [the product rule]). Let $h(x)=g(x) / B$. Then $h(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow p$, and we wish to prove that $1 / h(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow p$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We must show that there is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$
(3.14) \left|\frac{1}{h(x)}-1\right|<\epsilon \quad \text { whenever } 0<|x-p|<\delta .
$$
The difference to be estimated may be written as follows.
$$
(3.15) \left|\frac{1}{h(x)}-1\right|=\frac{|h(x)-1|}{|h(x)|}
$$
Since $h(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow p$, we can choose a $\delta>0$ such that both inequalities
$$
(3.16) |h(x)-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \quad \text { and } \quad|h(x)-1|<\frac{1}{2}
$$
are satisfied whenever $0<|x-p|<\delta$. The second of these inequalities implies $h(x)>\frac{1}{2}$ so $1 /|h(x)|=1 / h(x)<2$ for such $x$. Using this in (3.15) along with the first inequality in (3.16), we obtain (3.14). This completes the proof of (iv).

Please forgive the numbering not being left aligned. I am not sure how to do that with the math exchange formatting.

I understand how he did everything, but I do not understand how this proves the quotient rule. I suppose my point of confusion is the first paragraph. How exactly does it "it suffice[] to prove that $B / g(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow p$ and then appeal to (iii [the product rule])"?

Comment: $f/B\rightarrow A/B$ where $f \rightarrow A$ and $g \rightarrow B$.  He proves that $B/g \rightarrow 1$, so $fg = (f/B) (B/g) \rightarrow (A/B) \cdot 1 = A/B$ by the product rule.

Comment: I see. I guess I just needed it to be written a bit clearer. Should probably work on reworking proofs more thoroughly so I do not get confused in notation.